# как с помощью zipfile распаковать файлы без внутрнеей структуры?

Tags: python

Есть архив со структурой

```
icons.zip
---icons
----folder1
-----1.png
-----2.png
----folder2
...
```

есть код который должен создать папку в которую он будет складывать файлы из это архива по годам/месяцам последнего изменения этих файлов

```
папка скрипта
---2022
----05
-----1.png
----06
-----2.png
```

сам код

```
    def createrDir(name):
        if os.path.exists(name):
            return True
        else:
            try:
                os.makedirs(name)
                return True
            except OSError as e:
                print(f"Возникла ошибка: {e}")
                return False


    def checkDir(date):
        if createrDir(os.path.join(outputDir, date.strftime("%Y")) and
                           createrDir(os.path.join(self.outputDir, date.strftime("%Y"), date.strftime("%m")))):
            return True
        else:
            return False

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(inputDir)
        for file in zip.namelist():
            file_info = zip.getinfo(file)
            date = datetime.datetime(*file_info.date_time)
            file_name = os.path.basename(file_info.filename)
            new_file = os.path.join(outputDir, date.strftime("%Y"), date.strftime("%m"), os.path.basename(file_name))
            if file_info.is_dir():
                continue
            if checkDir(date):
                zip.extract(file_name, new_file)
```

но почему-то этот код создает такую структуру

```
---2022
----05
-----1.png #это директория
------icons
-------apps
--------1.png #Это уже файл
----06
-----2.png #это директория
------icons
-------apps
--------2.png #Это уже файл
```

почему zip.extract() распаковывает данные с явным указанием места со всей структурой? и как это исправить?

Comment: «почему» — потому что именно так и должен вести себя extract, всё в полном соответствии с [документацией](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract)

Comment: «как это исправить?» — например не использовать extract, а записывать файл вручную

Answer (score 1):

Короткий ответ:

> `ZipFile.extract(member, path=None, pwd=None)`
>
> ---
>
> Extract a member from the archive to the current working directory; member must be its full name or a ZipInfo object. Its file information is extracted as accurately as possible. **path specifies a different directory to extract to**. member can be a filename or a ZipInfo object. pwd is the password used for encrypted files as a bytes object.

То есть, в качестве второго параметра вы должны передавать не полный путь к файлу, а только путь к папке в которой он лежит.

---

Сделайте

```py
new_file = os.path.join(outputDir, date.strftime("%Y"), date.strftime("%m"))
```

и будет вам счастье

---

**PS:** вам не нужно танцев с бубном вокруг создания структуры папок вручную, достаточно сконструировать путь, а папки `zipfile` и сам создавать умеет

Comment: Никакого счастья не будет, потому что задача автора именно в том, чтобы изменить структуру

Comment: задача стоит именно сделать  именно  определенную структуру на выходе, при этом нельзя сначала распаковать архив и оттуда все скопировать, нужно сразу распаковывать в определенное место